# How to remove \r\n, white spaces and enable accents in Scrapy css?

Tags: css, web-scraping, scrapy

I am **VERY** begginer, so take it easy.
I'v googled how to fix it, but every answer i got was for Xpath and I am using CSS.

I am following this tutorial https://hexfox.com/p/scrape-your-cinemas-listings-to-get-a-daily-email-of-films-with-a-high-imdb-rating/ and reached this:

```
import scrapy

class CinemaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cinema"
    allowed_domains = ['cineroxy.com.br']
    start_urls = [
        'http://cineroxy.com.br/programacao-brisamar',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        movie_names = response.css('.titulo p::text').extract()
        for movie_name in movie_names:
            yield {
                'name': movie_name
            }
```

I'v executed properly so it will grap the info and create a json file:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>scrapy runspider cinema_scraper.py -o movies.json
```

But the result was this:

```
[
{"name": "\r\n                                        A Bailarina\r\n                                    "},
{"name": "\r\n                                        Assassins Creed - O Filme\r\n                                    "},
{"name": "\r\n                                        Cinquenta Tons Mais Escuros\r\n                                    "},
{"name": "\r\n                                        Minha M\u00e3e \u00e9 uma Pe\u00e7a 2\r\n                                    "},
{"name": "\r\n                                        Moana - Um Mar de Aventura\r\n                                    "},
{"name": "\r\n                                        Os Penetras 2 - Quem D\u00e1 Mais?\r\n                                    "},
{"name": "\r\n                                        Quatro Vidas de Um Cachorro\r\n                                    "},
{"name": "\r\n                                        Resident Evil 6: O \u00daltimo Cap\u00edtulo\r\n                                    "},
{"name": "\r\n                                        xXx: Reativado\r\n                                    "}
]
```

Now, I have 3 problems to solve with the output/extraction: The \r\n, the large white space and the bug when trying to extract accentuated words(**Resident Evil 6: O \u00daltimo Cap\u00edtulo** the original is **Resident Evil 6: O Último Capítulo**).

One thing this site's source code have in different with others i'v researched, is that it drops one line before writing the title:

```
<a href='../filme/resident-evil-6-o-ultimo-capitulo'>
    <img id="cphConteudo_rptBusca_imgFilme_7" title="Resident Evil 6: O Último Capítulo" class="img" src="http://www.cineroxy.com.br/suiteinstitucional/arquivos/filmes/040920161914411.jpg" />
    <div class="titulo">
        <p>
            Resident Evil 6: O Último Capítulo
        </p>
    </div>
<div class="passar-mouse">
    clique para ver os horários <img src="Arquitetura/Imagens/Icones/drop.png" alt="" />
</div>
</a>
```

Sorry for the long post and possible huge dumb mistakes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do note that `\uXXXX` sequences in JSON output is not a bug, it _is_ valid JSON syntax, simple one way of representing non-ASCII characters. A JSON-compatible reader/program will understand those `\uXXXX` sequences fine; A human reader, on the other hand, may not. `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING` setting mention in one of the answer will write UTF-8 encoded characters, without `\uXXXX` escaping. Many text editors/viewers will decode `\xc3\x9a` sequence (UTF-8 encoding of `\u00da`) from JSON text files as **Ú**, but it's still interpreted. A human would still have a hard time understanding `\xc3\x9a`.

Comment: I undestand that it is not a bug and programs can read that. BTW, I'm using Notepad++ for opening JSON. Should i use another text editor?

Answer (score 4):

```
 yield {
                'name': movie_name.strip()
            }
```

code:

```
"\r\n                                        A Bailarina\r\n                                    ".strip()
```

out:

```
'A Bailarina'
```

`strip()` will get rid of leading and tail whitespaces

Json:

That is to add in your `settings.py`:

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```

Document: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.2/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-encoding

Comment: Worked gracefuly. But still not accepting accents.  
`{"name": "Resident Evil 6: O \u00daltimo Cap\u00edtulo"},`,

Comment: It did not worked. My setting.py: http://puu.sh/tGBcX.py
This settings.py is located at  
    C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands